# Initial point exploitation for SDP solvers.

Tags: algorithms, semidefinite-programming

I've been using YALMIP with SeDuMi to solve a feasibility semidefinite program, that is, I want to find a feasible point in a set of the form $$F=\{S\in Sym_d(\mathbb{R}) : ||h(S)||\leq C(S_0), S\succeq 0\},$$ where $C(S_0)$ is a positive real and $h$ is an array of linear functions of $S$ (something like $h_j(S)=trace(A_j^tS)$, where $A_j$ are real matrices) and $Sym_d(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $d\times d$ symmetric matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

> So far, YALMIP seems to handle the norm constraint (and everything else) nicely, but I do have an initial guess $S_0$ (not necessarily feasible) and I would like to use this information somehow. Is this possible?

Something like minimizing $||S-S_0||$ subject to $S\in F$ makes sense to me, but it doesn't seem to work (the package is capable of solving it, but the solution is not as good as I expected).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should really post this question on the YALMIP forum instead. Regarding the question though. SeDuMi does not support initial guesses via YALMIP, and would almost never benefit from it due to the way the solver works. You model is nonconvex though as you have norm larger than, and YALMIP would thus never invoke SeDuMi on such a model

Comment: Thanks for answering me, professor, I'll post it there. Sorry, it is a convex problem, but I wrote it wrong and now I've edited it. My algorithm needs to solve this feasibility SDPs every iteration, and my initial guess for the $k$-th iteration would be $S_{k-1}+constant$, do you have any suggestion?